# Plot x-axis with time in Plotly Python

Tags: python, visualization

Is there a way to plot in Python using Plotly an x-axis, so it can show time, day, and week in different levels like the image here?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YddAr.png)

So x-axis should be like this: time (i.e. from 9am to 5pm), brackets showing the day (i.e time slots from 9am to 5pm is one day - Monday), day (i.e. Monday), bracket showing the week (i.e. days from Monday to Friday is week 1), week number (i.e. 1).

Comment: The x-axis needs to be in levels and it is not a date or time series but rather manual written time-day-week

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

you can do it like this:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks(indexed=True)-1
fig = px.bar(df, x=df.index, y="GOOG")
fig.show()
```

For more information: please check [Plotly Documentation](https://plotly.com/python/time-series/)

Comment: The x-axis needs to be in levels and it is not a date or time series but rather manual written time-day-week